# dropdown doesn't obey centering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get a series of controls positioned vertically and centered horizontally. The controls are coming out fine, but when I cause the dropdown to drop down, the dropdown text appears left justified on the screen rather than under the centered dropdown control.  I've spend a couple of hours on it and I can't get it right.  Help would surely be appreciated.  Here is what I am using:

```
<div style="margin-top:50px; text-align: center;">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Shift / Project2
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" type="text" id="xxx" style="margin-top:50px;">

</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: you should read this!!

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this issue using css like i did here:

http://www.bootply.com/zck8H4EVt4

Just add this to your CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

---

**// EDIT:**

Sorry, i've forgot about the btn-group class...

Just remove the CSS part from the first solution, add .btn-group to your dropdown and use .clearfix after your btn-group like i did here:

```
<div style="margin-top:50px; text-align: center;">
    <div class="dropdown btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Shift / Project2
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input id="xxx" style="margin-top:50px;" spellcheck="false" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">
</div>
```

Working example: http://www.bootply.com/lryEFqtmdp

Comment: hey, i've updated my answer. take a look at it. please mark as the right answer, if i solved your issue, :)